# Specify constructor, initialize later (Java)

Tags: java, game-engine

I am currently creating a 2D game engine in Java for android. The engine is basically an entity component system. You first create a blueprint (A wrapper for an id) which you can associate component types with. You can later "build" the blueprint. This means that an object for each of the types associated with the blueprint is initialized and put in an update-loop. An entity (Also a wrapper for an int id) is returned with which you can access the components.

When adding the component no object is initialized which means i cant provide a constructor at that time, this is what i'd like to solve somehow.

This is how i currently associate a component type with a blueprint:

```
public <T extends Component> void addComponent(BluePrint bluePrint, Class<T> type) {
    bluePrintMap.get(bluePrint.getId()).add(type);
}
```

Id like to return a method reference or just provide the constructor parameters as arguments to addComponent and store them for later use. I'm not sure how to approach this problem since i don't even know the the length of the constructor arguments beforehand. Any input is appreatiated.

Edit:
A possible solution is to actually create an instance of the component and later create a copy when the user decides to build the blueprint, but this would cause some other problems for me.

Comment: 1) The general approach can work.  2) The "I don't even know how many arguments" problem may be solvable using methods with variable numbers of arguments (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) or by passing in `Collection` or array objects.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your question, but could you pass in a `Supplier<Component>` which would serve as a factory that would be called when it was time to create the component?

Comment: @DavidConrad thanks for the input, the thought is that when the components are created i have already saved information that specifes how they should be created. When creating a object only an id is provided to the method which has already been mapped to the constructor data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i just went with the solution i provided in the edit, it seems to work very well so far and i also get type safety which is nice. A drawback is that 
if i want to make it easy for the user when creating the script components i think the engine has to perform a copy using serialization which is kind off slow.